# how to rename random number from file name to sequent number?

Tags: python, directory, file-rename

Hi i'm trying to rename my files in a directory from (2015_001.txt,2015_005.txt,2015_009.txt..etc) to (2015_001.txt,2015_002.txt,2015_003.tx..etc). I'm new to python, can anyone help me?

I tried using loop but all file will not in series anymore
this is the code I tried so far

```
import re
import os
_src = "C:/ZTD/pwv2015/"
_ext = ".txt"
endsWithNumber = re.compile(r'(\d+)'+(re.escape(_ext))+'$')
for filename in os.listdir(_src):
    m = endsWithNumber.search(filename)
    if m:
        os.rename(filename, _src+'2015_' + str(m.group(1)).zfill(3)+_ext)
    else:
        os.rename(filename, _src+'2015_' + str(0).zfill(3)+_ext)
```

Comment: What is the relation of these names? Did you want to sort the names in ascending order before doing the rename?

Comment: these files already in ascending order with 4 points interval . I want the names of the file has 1 point interval – @tdelaney

Comment: Whether a directory lists in alphabetical order is file system dependent.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have an easier time with the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/glob.html) module for finding files and f-strings for renaming. Also, for the sake of teaching modern python, I'm using the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pathlib.html) and its `glob` method. Try this:

```py
import os
import pathlib

src = pathlib.Path("C:/ZTD/pwv2015")
pattern = "2015_[0-9][0-9][0-9].txt"
inpaths = sorted(src.glob(pattern))
for outnum, inpath in enumerate(inpaths, 1):
    outpath = src / f"2015_{outnum:03d}.txt"
    if outpath != inpath:
        os.rename(inpath, outpath)
```

Note that since the input and output directory are identical, we have to be careful with overwriting files. However, in this instance we "compress" the range, so if we go in sorted order, the input file numbers will always be greater or equal to the output file numbers, so we are okay.

Also, when you test this, replace `os.rename` with `print`, just to be sure ;-)

Comment: Hello sir, thanks for the help. But I forgot to mention that in the file list, there are also some files with 4 digit numbers e.g. 2015_1001.txt . What can I add to continue the rename order? @Homer512

Comment: @adhid Well, glob patterns are a bit restricted compared to regexes so depending on how specific you want to be with your pattern, you need to switch back to them. What you could do, for example, is ```"2015_[0-9]*[0-9].txt"```. Which would be number + any characters any length + number. Of course this could also match something like ```2015_1_abcd_4.txt```. So you need to have a good idea what files are in the directory